# How to do 'show all posts except mine' in MEAN stack?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I created my MEAN stack app based on [this tutorial](http://engineering.paiza.io/entry/2016/03/10/115345).
This is my thoughtsIndex.js in /client/app/thoughtsIndex/. You can think 'thought' as post.

```
angular.module('meanGoroApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/thoughtsIndex/thoughtsIndex.html',
        controller: 'ThoughtsIndexCtrl',
        resolve: {
            query: function($stateParams) {
            return {
              // I need help here!!
            }
          }
        }
      })

      .state('collectedThoughtsIndex', {
        url: '/users/:userId/collected',
        templateUrl: 'app/thoughtsIndex/thoughtsIndex.html',
        controller: 'ThoughtsIndexCtrl',
        resolve: {
            query: function($stateParams) {
                return {
                    collectedBy: $stateParams.userId
                }
            }
        }
      })

      .state('userThoughtsIndex', {
        url: '/users/:userId',
        templateUrl: 'app/thoughtsIndex/thoughtsIndex.html',
        controller: 'ThoughtsIndexCtrl',
        resolve: {
            query: function($stateParams) {
                return { user: $stateParams.userId };
            }
        }
      });
  });
```

'collectedThoughtsIndex' state and 'userThoughtsIndex' state are working fine.

Problem is, when the state is 'main', I want to show all thoughts in db, except current user's thoughts. If there is no current user, I want to show all thoughts in db.

[I asked to the tutorial author](http://engineering.paiza.io/entry/2016/03/10/115345#comment-2592620097), and he said try {user: {$ne: $stateParams.userId}}. But this gave me this error.

```
    Unhandled rejection CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path "user"
    at MongooseError.CastError (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/mongoose/lib/error/cast.js:19:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:147:13)
    at ObjectId.castForQuery (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectid.js:187:15)
    at cast (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cast.js:141:34)
    at Query.cast (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2570:10)
    at Query.find (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1087:10)
    at /Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2164:21
    at Query.exec (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2157:10)
From previous event:
    at index (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/server/api/thought/thought.controller.js:78:55)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at Function.handle (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
    at router (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:91:12)
    at trim_prefix (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
    at /Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Volumes/Garage/GORO/mean_goro/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
```

So far, I tried

```
{user: {$ne: $stateParams.userId}}
{user: {$not: $stateParams.userId}}
{$ne: {user: $stateParams.userId}}
{$not: {user: $stateParams.userId}}
```

but none of these worked.
Please help me.. I'm desperate :-(

++
This is my 'thoughtsIndex.controller.js' file.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('meanGoroApp')
  .controller('ThoughtsIndexCtrl', function ($scope, $http, Auth, $location, query, socket) {
    $scope.busy = true;
    $scope.noMoreData = false;

    $http.get('/api/thoughts', {params: {query: query}}).success(function(thoughts) {
        $scope.thoughts = thoughts;
      socket.syncUpdates('thought', thoughts);
        if($scope.thoughts.length < 20) {
            $scope.noMoreData = true;
        }
        $scope.busy = false;
    });

    $scope.nextPage = function() {
        if($scope.busy) { return; }
        $scope.busy = true;
        var lastId = $scope.thoughts[$scope.thoughts.length-1]._id;
        var pageQuery = _.merge(query, {_id: {$lt: lastId}});

        $http.get('/api/thoughts', {params: {query: pageQuery}}).success(function(thoughts) {
            $scope.thoughts = $scope.thoughts.concat(thoughts);
            $scope.busy = false;
            if(thoughts.length === 0) {
                $scope.noMoreData = true;
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.isOwner = function(obj) {
      return Auth.isLoggedIn() && obj && obj.user && obj.user._id === Auth.getCurrentUser()._id;
    }

    $scope.isCollected = function(obj) {
        return Auth.isLoggedIn() && obj && obj.collectedBy && obj.collectedBy.indexOf(Auth.getCurrentUser()._id) !== -1;
    }

    $scope.isLoggedIn = function() {
      if(!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        $location.path('/login');
        $location.replace();
        return;
      }
    }

    $scope.submit = function() {
      $http.post('/api/thoughts', $scope.thought).success(function() {
        $location.path('/users/' + Auth.getCurrentUser()._id);
        $scope.clearInput();
      });
    }

    $scope.clearInput = function() {
      $scope.thought.main_sentence = null;
      $scope.thought.sub_sentence = null;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please post your ThoughtsIndexController file please

Comment: @atefth I posted the controller file as you mentioned. I hope you can check again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **collectedThoughtsIndex** and the **userThoughtsIndex** routes takes the userId params from the url but the **main** route takes no such params.

> Your api call takes the query object that you generate from the stateProvider and makes a call to the server. However, since you have no query params to generate in the **main** route, you have to make the api call without any query params.

You have to update the backend in this way -

- when no query params are passed
- if a user is logged in

  - return all thoughts except his
- else

  - return all thoughts

I hope this makes sense to you. :)

Comment: I'm really newbie for angular so I can't really figure it out by myself. But I didn't know that the userId params is taken from the url, so I ended up creating 'othersThoughts' state with '/users/:userId/others' url. I still want to do with the '/' url, but I don't have a clue how to do that. But your answer helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: I glad to be of help and you can accept my answer if it solved your problem :)